# Codeigniter 4 transactions aren't rolling back

Tags: codeigniter, transactions, codeigniter-4

I'll admit I'm new to CI4 (plenty of experience in v3) but I can't see what the issue is here and I've boiled it down to a very straightforward test.. It seems no matter what I do the transactions (even in test mode) do not roll back. Consider this simple test I have in my model: In this instance I'm trying to force the rollback just to confirm it works yet the 'test' entry is inserted every time. Likewise I've tried using `$this->db->transStart(true);` and `$this->db->transComplete();` method too; same result, it still inserts the record. Below is my App/Config/Database setup

```
  public function addNewFamilyMemberAndUser($data){
        $this->db->transBegin();
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO `families` (`id`, `family_number`) VALUES (NULL, "test")');
        /*$this->db->table('users')
            ->set('first_name', $data['invite_first_name'])
            ->set('last_name', $data['invite_last_name'])
            ->set('user_type', 'member')
            ->set('is_active', 1)
            ->set('is_primary', 0)
            ->set('created_at', dateToMysql('now',true))
            ->set('email', $data['invite_email'])
            ->insert();
        $userId = $this->db->insertID();
        
        if($userId){
            $this->db->table('family_members')
            ->set('family_id', $data['familyId'])
            ->set('user_id', $userId)
            ->set('family_member_type', 'parent')
            ->set('created_at', dateToMysql('now',true))
            ->set('is_user', 1)
            ->insert();
        }*/
        $this->db->transRollback();

        
    }
```

config settings are overridden in .env for the port (3308), database, username and password

```
public $default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];
```

Comment: Are your tables transactional?

Comment: @Dharman ugh what a stupid thing to miss. I've been using the migrations for the first time in CI4 with the forge class and I completely overlooked that these are defaulting to MyISAM unless I specifically pass in `['ENGINE' => 'InnoDB']` as the 3rd parameter to  `forge->createTable`.. A waste of a post! Thanks for the help